# How to 'enable extension hstore'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I enabled hstore using the below code.

```
class SetupHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore"
 end
 def self.down
  execute "DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS hstore"
 end
end
```

Once I migrated the file 'enable_extension hstore' line appeared in schema file.
But when I used the same code in another system i got an error like
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist

By droping that schema and migrating it also i tried to enable it but still its not working.

Comment: How did you install Postgres on that server? For most Linux distributions you need to install another package ("postgresql-contrib" or something similar) to make the additional modules available

Comment: I already installed 'postgres-contrib' its in the system, but it is not working.

Comment: And what happens when you run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore` manually?

Comment: 'CREATE: command not found' i got this error

Comment: That is a SQL statement that needs to be run using a SQL client tool (e.g. `psql`) not on the command line of your operating system

Comment: while executing this command 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore' got like this  
```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
NOTICE:  extension "hstore" already exists, skipping
CREATE EXTENSION
```